# Choose value of element from priority list

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML document which may contain equivalent non-sibling elements in different namespaces. I want to get the value of the highest priority one from a list I provide.

e.g.

```
<ns1:thing>
  <ns1:info>
    <ns1:title>Some title</ns1:title>
  </ns1:info>
  <ns2:metadata>
    <ns2:mainTitle>Main title</ns2:mainTitle>
    <ns2:altTitle>Alt title</ns2:altTitle>
  </ns2:metadata>
  ...
```

I want to pick one of them and output its value, but all of these elements are optional, so I would need to go through a list and look for each one, or perhaps more XSLT-like, try to apply them in sequence and then try the next one if the element cannot be found?
The priority list might be, say, `ns2:metadata/ns2:mainTitle` > `ns1:info/ns1:title` > `ns2:metadata/ns2:altTitle` > `"Fallback"`, which given all optional elements are present as above, would result in:

```
<html:title>Main title</html:title>
```

I can only use XSLT 1.0 (`xsltproc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy in XSLT/XPath 2 or later to simply provide a sequence `(ns2:metadata/ns2:mainTitle, ns1:info/ns1:title, ns2:metadata/ns2:altTitle, 'Fallback')` and then take the first `(ns2:metadata/ns2:mainTitle, ns1:info/ns1:title, ns2:metadata/ns2:altTitle, 'Fallback')[1]` to select based on the first available item.

With XSLT 1 this is more difficult to express in a compact and elegant way, perhaps you can live with a hard-coded `xsl:choose`:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="ns2:metadata/ns2:mainTitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns2:metadata/ns2:mainTitle"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="ns1:info/ns1:title">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:info/ns1:title"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="ns2:metadata/ns2:altTitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns2:metadata/ns2:altTitle"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>Fallback</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

perhaps wrapped in a callable or apply-able (probably using mode) template.